# Extracting more than one video using mkvextract?

Tags: mkv

I have container stream that contains more than one video. i want to identify that at which index the video are present and want to extract elementary stream using those index or ID.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

identify track IDs in a mkv video:

```
mkvmerge -i video.mkv
```